# Funciones banco con txt

Tags: java, java-ee

Estoy realizando un proyecto que simula un banco sencillo, el cual consulta, retira y consigna saldo a otras cuentas. Por medio de un `txt` que funciona como base de datos (Cuenta/Clave/Saldo):

[image: Ejemplo]

Este proyecto se realiza en Java EJB, Cliente/Servidor por lo que tiene lo siguiente:

SessionBean (Aqui van los BussinessMEthod)

```
@Override
public String mostrarCuentas() {
    File archivo = null;
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String ver_cuentas="";

    try {
       // Apertura del fichero y creacion de BufferedReader para poder
       // hacer una lectura comoda (disponer del metodo readLine()).
       archivo = new File ("C:/Users/david/Desktop/prybanco/bd.txt");
       fr = new FileReader (archivo);
       br = new BufferedReader(fr);

       // Lectura del fichero
       String linea;
       while((linea=br.readLine())!=null){
          //System.out.println(linea);
          ver_cuentas+=linea+"\n";
       }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
       // En el finally cerramos el fichero, para asegurarnos
       // que se cierra tanto si todo va bien como si salta 
       // una excepcion.
       try{                    
          if( null != fr ){   
             fr.close();     
          }                  
       }catch (Exception e2){ 
          e2.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

    return ver_cuentas;
}

@Override
public String validarSesion(String n_cuenta, String clave) {
    File archivo = null;
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String ver_cuentas="";

    try {
       // Apertura del fichero y creacion de BufferedReader para poder
       // hacer una lectura comoda (disponer del metodo readLine()).
       archivo = new File ("C:/Users/david/Desktop/prybanco/bd.txt");
       fr = new FileReader (archivo);
       br = new BufferedReader(fr);          

       // Lectura del fichero
       String linea;
       while((linea=br.readLine())!=null){
            String[] parts = linea.split("\\s+");
            if(n_cuenta.equals(parts[0]) && clave.equals(parts[1])){
                System.out.println("Cuenta--------Clave-------Saldo");
                ver_cuentas = parts[0]+"    "+parts[1]+"    "+parts[2];  



            }else{
                System.out.println("cuenta o clave erroneos");
            }
            //ver_cuentas+=linea+"\n";
       }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
       // En el finally cerramos el fichero, para asegurarnos
       // que se cierra tanto si todo va bien como si salta 
       // una excepcion.
       try{                    
          if( null != fr ){   
             fr.close();     
          }                  
       }catch (Exception e2){ 
          e2.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

    return ver_cuentas;
}
```

y el siguiente método (Con el que tengo problemas), donde pienso poner por medio del switch retiro y consignación.

```
 @Override
public Integer businessMethod(int parameter) {
    FileWriter fichero = null;
    PrintWriter pw = null;

     File archivo = null;
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    //String ver_cuentas="";
    int nuevoValor = 0;

    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

// Si queremos añadir al final de un fichero ya existente, 
// simplemente debemos poner un flag a true como segundo parámetro 
// del constructor de FileWriter : 
// FileWriter fichero = new FileWriter("prueba.txt",true);

    try
    {

        fichero = new FileWriter("C:/Users/david/Desktop/prybanco/bd.txt");
        pw = new PrintWriter(fichero);

        String linea;
        while((linea=br.readLine())!=null){
            String[] parts = linea.split("\\s+");
            System.out.println("Cuenta--------Clave-------Saldo");
                //ver_cuentas = parts[0]+"    "+parts[1]+"    "+parts[2];
            switch(parameter){

            case 1:
                System.out.println("Ingrese monto a retirar");
                int monto=scn.nextInt();

                int test = parseInt(parts[2]);
                if( test<monto){
                    System.out.println("Fondos insuficientes");
                }else{
                    nuevoValor=test-monto;
                    //System.out.println(nuevoValor);
                }

                break;


            case 2:
                System.out.println("Ingrese cuenta de destino");
                String cdest =scn.next();


        }
            /*if(n_cuenta.equals(parts[0]) && clave.equals(parts[1])){
                System.out.println("Cuenta--------Clave-------Saldo");
                ver_cuentas = parts[0]+"    "+parts[1]+"    "+parts[2];  



            }*/
            //ver_cuentas+=linea+"\n";
       }


       /* for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            pw.println("Linea " + i);
        */

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
       try {
       // Nuevamente aprovechamos el finally para 
       // asegurarnos que se cierra el fichero.
       if (null != fichero)
          fichero.close();
       } catch (Exception e2) {
          e2.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
    return nuevoValor;
}
```

Ahora creo un EnterpriseClient(MAin), el cual ejecuta el cliente donde se asignan los metodos con el siguiente codigo:

```
public class Main {

@EJB
private static menejoCuentasRemote menejoCuentas;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner opciones = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println(menejoCuentas.mostrarCuentas());

    System.out.println("numero de cuenta");
    String cuenta = opciones.next();
    System.out.println("contraseña");
    String contrasenna = opciones.next();

    System.out.println("CUENTA----PASS----SALDO---------------");

    System.out.println(menejoCuentas.validarSesion(cuenta, contrasenna));


    if(menejoCuentas.validarSesion(cuenta, contrasenna)!=null){
        System.out.println("1.Retiro\n 2.Transferencia");
        int ope =opciones.nextInt();
        System.out.println(menejoCuentas.businessMethod(ope));



    }else{
        System.out.println("no hay cuenta");
    }

}

}
```

Ejecuto y sucede lo siguiente:
[image: Ejemplo]

ingreso los datos de una cuenta, me la muestra sin problemas, cuando presiono 1, para retirar me aparece un 0, y no me pide el monto a retirar ni me muestra el saldo actualizado.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Hola David, por favor, cambia las imágenes por texto para que sea más fácil poder ayudarte. Gracias.

Comment: Ponle un default al switch como buena práctica y aprovéchalo para ver si te queda basura en el scanner como sugiere una de las respuestas, pintando el valor que se está procesando y haciendo que haga otra iteración.

Answer (score 1):

Te falta añadir un break en el switch por eso no te deja introducir el valor y sigue leyendo hasta el return.

```
 @Override
public Integer businessMethod(int parameter) {
    FileWriter fichero = null;
    PrintWriter pw = null;

     File archivo = null;
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    //String ver_cuentas="";
    int nuevoValor = 0;

    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

// Si queremos añadir al final de un fichero ya existente, 
// simplemente debemos poner un flag a true como segundo parámetro 
// del constructor de FileWriter : 
// FileWriter fichero = new FileWriter("prueba.txt",true);

    try
    {

        fichero = new FileWriter("C:/Users/david/Desktop/prybanco/bd.txt");
        pw = new PrintWriter(fichero);

        String linea;
        while((linea=br.readLine())!=null){
            String[] parts = linea.split("\\s+");
            System.out.println("Cuenta--------Clave-------Saldo");
                //ver_cuentas = parts[0]+"    "+parts[1]+"    "+parts[2];
            switch(parameter){

            case 1:
                System.out.println("Ingrese monto a retirar");
                int monto=scn.nextInt();

                int test = parseInt(parts[2]);
                if( test<monto){
                    System.out.println("Fondos insuficientes");
                }else{
                    nuevoValor=test-monto;
                    //System.out.println(nuevoValor);
                }

                break;


            case 2:
                System.out.println("Ingrese cuenta de destino");
                String cdest =scn.next();
                break;


        }
            /*if(n_cuenta.equals(parts[0]) && clave.equals(parts[1])){
                System.out.println("Cuenta--------Clave-------Saldo");
                ver_cuentas = parts[0]+"    "+parts[1]+"    "+parts[2];  



            }*/
            //ver_cuentas+=linea+"\n";
       }


       /* for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            pw.println("Linea " + i);
        */

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
       try {
       // Nuevamente aprovechamos el finally para 
       // asegurarnos que se cierra el fichero.
       if (null != fichero)
          fichero.close();
       } catch (Exception e2) {
          e2.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
    return nuevoValor;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, ya lo añadi, y sigue saltándose el switch.

Comment: Tienes el código subido a Github para poder probarlo? @DavidAlejandroLarrota

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que el problema sea que cuando escribes la opción 1 (`1.Retiro`) luego pulsas `Enter` así que realmente estás escribiendo `1 + Salto de línea (\n)`.

Ahora el buffer tiene:

```
1\n
```

Luego el primer nextInt "consume" el número y deja pendiente el salto de línea `\n`:

```
1\n
 ^
  \__ Se consume el 1
```

Ahora el buffer tiene:

```
\n
```

Después, ingresas el número 2 y presionas Enter. El buffer tiene:

```
\n2\n
```

Así que cuando llamas a `nextInt()` éste no puede consumir ningún número.

Una posible solución sería consumir el salto de línea una vez haces el `nextInt()`:

Por ejemplo:

```
int ope = opciones.nextInt();
opciones.nextLine();
```

Ten encuenta que deberías hacer esto cada vez que usas `nextInt()`, así que también deberías agregarlo en este caso:

```
int monto = scn.nextInt();
scn.nextLine();
```